# Prepare statement like clause with chinese character

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform and a textbox which will pass the value to a prepared statement like this

```
searchKey = "member_chinese_name";
field_name = "member_chinese_name";
daoQuery = "SELECT * FROM member where member_chinese_name like @" + searchKey;

sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(daoQuery, databaseConnection);
MessageBox.Show(field_name + " " + field_value1);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@"+field_name , field_value1 + "%"));
sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

the whole query is (select * from member where member_chinese_name like 中文字%;)

the query has no result run in my winform, but i run the sql in phpmyadmin (select * from member where member_chinese_name like '中文字%') is valid

Anyone know what is the problem?

Remarks (search english is ok)

Comment: It should be something in the default locale or character sets supported by the database engine. I don't know enough of MySql to be of help on this. Please add the tag MySql to your question

Comment: Perhaps this question could help you to start on your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940695/how-to-perform-mysql-fulltext-search-with-chinese-characters

Comment: Offtopic: For what you call ExecuteNonQuery? Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the parameter you are sending for the search. It should be `@searchKey` instead of `@" + searchKey;` and you can also choose `sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` instead of `sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter` thus code would look like

```
searchKey = "member_chinese_name";
field_name = "member_chinese_name";
daoQuery = "SELECT * FROM member where member_chinese_name like @sKey";
sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(daoQuery, databaseConnection);
MessageBox.Show(field_name + " " + field_value1);
//not sure which variable stores 中文字
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sKey", field_value1+"%");
```